# Convergence of a sum with a power

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, summation

I'm struggling to show that the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(A_i+\frac{2\varepsilon}{2^i}\right)^s$$
can be taken as $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(A_i\right)^s$ for arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$. So it's showing that the fraction added can be taken to just be $0$.

Also, I'm new so apologies if things aren't quite right. I was struggling to word the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, *Welcome to the site !*

Consider
$$a_i=\left(A_i+2^{1-i} \epsilon \right)^s\implies \log(a_i)=s \log\left(A_i+2^{1-i} \epsilon \right)$$ Use Taylor series to get
$$\log\left(A_i+2^{1-i} \epsilon \right)=\log (A_i)+\frac{2^{1-i} \epsilon }{A_i}-\frac{2^{1-2 i} \epsilon ^2}{A_i^2}+O\left(\epsilon^3\right)$$ Multiply by $s$ and continue with Taylor since
$$a_i=e^{\log(a_i)}=A_i^s+2^{1-i} s \epsilon  A_i^{s-1}+2^{1-2 i} (s-1) s \epsilon ^2 A_i^{s-2}+O\left(\epsilon^3\right)$$ Now, make $\epsilon$ very small and make the summation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Took a while to understand but that's brilliant, thank you

Comment: @JustinorbitYou are welcome ! I am glad to help. Cheers :-)